# How to use material qrcode icon in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to show a material icon in Angular 8. But it doesnt show

So i try to show the qrcode symbol like this:

```
<mat-icon class="patient-table-link patient-table-link-view material-icons"  [routerLink]="openEcheqSelectorQrcode(row.participantId)" routerLinkActive="router-link-active"  >qrcode-scan</mat-icon>
```

But it doesnt show the right icon.

But this works:

```
<mat-icon class="patient-table-link patient-table-link-view" [routerLink]="getViewLink(row.participantId)" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" >visibility</mat-icon>

``
So the library is installed correct

That the Qrcode symbol will be displayed.

Thank you
```

Comment: So where do you gather that `qrcode-scan` would show a qr-code. To my knowledge angular material doesn't have a qr-code icon?

Comment: Yes, oke, thank you. I didnt knew that. That is why I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So solved!! angular material doesn't have such Icon. That is why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

There is such an icon.

```
<mat-icon>qr_code</mat-icon>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-icon-wqkjvp?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You would to use

```
qr_code_2

qr_code
```